# Ubuntu Python, install packages with user or sudo

Tags: python, pip

I am new at Python and Ubuntu. I really struggle to decide the best way of installing Python packages on Ubuntu. I am using VIM so I cannot use Anaconda since they do no "talk".

I have two options:

1. Install with: pip3 install --user foo. This works find but according to     [python4astronomers](https://python4astronomers.github.io/installation/packages.html) you should never use --user. It will work very bad.
2. Use apt-get but then I got old packages
3. Use sudo pip, but that can get bad code into my system.

I do not want to use virtual environments. I want to be able to use all packages I have installed when I use Python. I normally use Jupyter.

I find it strange that Python installation is so difficult on Linux compared with Windows.

Which of these is the correct way?

Comment: I've always used `pip install <packageName>`

Comment: Why don't vim and anaconda "talk"? And what's the issue with virtualenvs? Those two are the recommended ways.

Comment: When I inwoke Pyhon from vim it is using the system version and not the Anaconda version. And the same with YouCompleteMe. It only sees the system version of Python.

Comment: Then you are launching vim "in a weird way". Vim should inherit the `$PATH` variable from your shell, which makes both of them find the Anaconda Python interpreter.

Comment: Okay. Then I probably have broken something. I will try a clean install of Ubuntu and start over again.

Comment: What you mean VIM and Anaconda don't talk? I guess you are mistaken. Vim is a file editor and Anaconda is a package repository for science in python. And using virtual envs is VERY recommended.

Comment: But when using a virtualenv, I have to install all packages I need in each environment. In data science I often use a lot of packages at once. It is a big hassel to always have to install everything each time I want to test a new package.

Comment: Those are not downsides, really. Most of the packages are precompiled, so installing them will take a a few seconds. And having isolated, reproducible environments helps you manage and share your work more easily.

Comment: Okay. If make a script which install all my standard packages it should be okay

Comment: But I not managed to find out how to use my virtual env. together with Jupyter. When I start a Jupyter notebook I only get the base kernel.

Comment: I would use the --user option. I don't really see how it is an issue, even after reading your link. This is also my preferred way to install python packages.

Comment: Regarding jupyter. **activate** the environment, first, then `pip install ipython` and then `ipython kernel install --user`. That's it. If you want more dependencies in there, then use `conda` or `pip` respectively

Comment: Really this question might have been better of as "How can I call a specific python environment from inside Vim" Try running "which python" to debug what is happening... Also try environments and to conda create -n py2 Python=2,  source activate py2 etc...

Comment: I am using neovim on ubuntu. I just have to try. Until now I have only used the python3 on ubuntu.